# ListView : items aren't stable

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am working on a "users" activity that show online users in a chat application, to show them I am using a ListView and every item contains the profil photo, the name and an extra textview about the online user.I am storing images in FirebaseStorage.

the problem is that when I scroll the items aren't stable and some images of other users are shown in the wrong item, and I have to wait around 2 seconds until the view becomes stable.

what if I used RecyclerView ? will it change and solve this issue ? I need your suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem you should do so. Otherwise no one is going to guess what the problem is. But, yes, for a scrolling partial view like this you can use RecyclerView. There are many tutorials out there on implementing this view.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you scroll up and down, these views are getting re-drawed with wrong options so always specify both if-else conditions cause listview  doesn't know the previous state/conditions/values of our widgets.